# golang get hardware info (uuid/hwid)

Tags: python, go, authentication, hardware

I am trying get a unique hardware info such as the uuid of a device for a client based application that will have an authentication process.

In python it would be something like:

```py
import subprocess

hwid = str(subprocess.check_output('wmic csproduct get uuid')).split('\\r\\n')[1].strip('\\r').strip()

print(hwid)
```

Ouput:

```
9F23624C-33F1-3244-A2ZD-ABF6CC8E5FB5
```

How do can I replicate this function in go, and assign it to a variable  ? `uuid := xxx`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a solution using, os/exec:

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {

    const xx = "cmd.exe"

    var stdout bytes.Buffer
    cmd := exec.Command(xx, "/c", "wmic csproduct get uuid")
    cmd.Stdout = &stdout
    cmd.Run()

    out := stdout.String()

    fmt.Println(out)

}
```

Output:

```
UUID
9F23624C-33F1-3244-A2ZD-ABF6CC8E5FB5
```